# Error al crear un documento Word

Tags: vb.net, windows-forms, interop

Estoy tratando de crear un documento Word desde Ms Visual Basic 2010 por medio de un boton en un formulario, ya he agregado la referencia de `Microsoft Word 15.0 Object Library` al proyecto, el documento Word se crea satisfactoriamente y lo guarda, pero después de hacer eso me muestra el siguiente error. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto mi código:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub btncrear_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btncrear.Click

        'Declara la variable.
        Dim objWD As Word.Application
        'Crea una nueva instancia de Word
        objWD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        'Agrega un nuevo documento en blanco
        objWD.Documents.Add()
        'Agrega Texto.
        objWD.Selection.TypeText("Hola mundo")
        'Guarda el documento
        objWD.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(FileName:="cotizacion.doc")
        objWD = objWD.Documents.Open(FileName:="cotizacion.doc")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Tienes que aplicar el uso del API de word, esto lo encuentras en Office.com Lee la documentacion completa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El mensaje es claro, estás tratando convertir un tipo a otro de forma incorrecta. Tu variable `objWD` es del tipo `Word.Application`, cuando abres un documento es necesario definir otra variable de tipo `Document`.

Por ejemplo:

```
Dim archivoWord As Word.Document 
archivoWord = objWD.Documents.Open(FileName:="cotizacion.doc")
```

o

```
Dim archivoWord = objWD.Documents.Open(FileName:="cotizacion.doc")
```

Comment: Gracias, adicional mente quiero preguntar si tal ves tienes el conocimiento de como cambiar el formato a cierta parte del texto que estoy ingresando al word desde la aplicación, por ejemplo que ese hola mundo salga con arial 22 y en negrilla, y el resto del texto que agregue salga de otra manera.

Comment: @KevinBurbano Podrías dar por aceptada la respuesta y genera una nueva pregunta sobre los formatos.

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias